# Free & private version control hosting website

Tags: php, git, svn, version-control

Any good Git or Subversion for non-public/non-open project. I have narrowed it down to these three. Now which of the 3 would you recommend. I am looking for secure, with a good up-time, private, support for 3-4 users and 1 repository and a space of about >200-300 MB

1. **assembla** - http://offers.assembla.com/free-subversion-hosting/
2. **unfuddle** - http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans
3. **xp-dev** - http://xp-dev.com/pricing

I know GitHub is awesome for but it's free for public/open projects only and Google Code is only for open project. Am i right over here and what about SoundForge is it also for  public projects.

Comment: So you are looking for a hoster, not version control software? Do you need a server? i.e. are you working on multiple machines on the same time?

Comment: what about mercurial? have you considered that? bitbucket fits your needs for mercurial.

Comment: $12 a month is too much? With a free service you can never know if they are going to discontinue it at some point... besides that, you already said you like github. Anyway, if you have a server consider hosting the repository for yourself. You could install [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious) and have something github-ish for free.

Comment: @knittl I am looking specifically for version control only

Comment: @WebDeveloper: I don't understand. "Version Control only"? Version Control is a thing to do, version control systems is the software to use. And yet in your question you are listing hosting providers and ask which of them is best …

Comment: @knittl OH now i get what u mean now. I am looking for VC hosting. Do you recommend anything

Answer (score 0):

I use assembla.

It's free and it's working great :) never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will approach Mercurial and bitbucket.org? This solution very simple and has a private repo.

Comment: Since yesterday, Bitbucket supports Git repositories as well: http://blog.bitbucket.org/2011/10/03/bitbucket-now-rocks-git/ (also private in the free plan)

Comment: Yep, and it's absolutelly free =)